# use of constant

Tags: meaning-in-context, paragraphs

I read this article on the Syrian upheaval on a Prospect Blog.

> A week is a long time in the diplomatic efforts surrounding the Syrian conflict. Just when it looked as though key elements were coalescing towards convening a US-UK-Russia-sponsored conference to negotiate a way out of the political deadlock, events on the ground took over again. Rather than an aberration, “events” have in fact been a constant of what is better characterised as a game of diplomatic catch-up, in which the main players on the chessboard have been firmly rooted in Syria, and now the wider region, for over two years.

I am not able to understand why the "events" are "a constant"? Does s/he mean constant as in a maths equation's constant? Would *described*, instead of "characterised", not have been a better word to use in the last sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrasing is slightly unusual/non-standard, in that most writers wouldn't use ***of*** there...
(Google Books: [a constant **in** what](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22definitely%20second-rate%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20constant%20in%20what%22&oq=%22a%20constant%20in%20what%22&gs_l=serp.3...1178443.1183644.0.1183965.18.18.0.0.0.0.178.1649.15j3.18.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.rG-j_BlIJgI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bGE&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1186&bih=930) - 1290 hits; [a constant **of** what](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22definitely%20second-rate%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20constant%20of%20what%22&oq=%22a%20constant%20of%20what%22&gs_l=serp.3...505594.506534.2.506893.4.3.1.0.0.0.154.329.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.ev_5RTXwf6U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bGE&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1186&bih=930) - 23 hits).

> “events” have in fact been a constant [factor] **in** what is ... a game of diplomatic catch-up.

Note that the specific word "factor" isn't necessarily the only word that could fit there, and it's not really true to say anything has been "elided/omitted". In fact, Google Books has 3440 instances of [the one constant in my life](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20one%20constant%20in%20my%20life%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only 23 for [the one constant **factor** in my life](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20one%20constant%20in%20my%20life%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20one%20constant%20factor%20in%20my%20life%22&oq=%22the%20one%20constant%20factor%20in%20my%20life%22&gs_l=serp.3...7419.8776.0.9069.7.7.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.FaRRDqG7Pds&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.ZWU&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1186&bih=930) (the same meaning).

---

It's worth pointing out that Brits, at least, would understand *events* here as meaning *unplanned and unexpected events in the real world, that significantly **affect the political process**.* Echoing what Prime Minister Harold Macmillan supposedly replied, when asked what he most feared...

> ["***Events***, dear boy, ***events***!"](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/personal-view/3577416/As-Macmillan-never-said-thats-enough-quotations.html)

---

The writer's choice of *characterised* rather than, for example, *described* is perfectly normal, and could actually be ***described*** as the "better" choice in his exact context (but it would definitely be the "worse" choice if I'd used it in my own sentence here). That's because when you "characterise" something, this normally implies you're looking past superficial details - actively seeking out and describing the "inner, abiding, more significant characteristics".

Comment: Both Collins and the AHD choose to list the non-mathematical sense of the noun 'constant' before the mathematical one.

Comment: @Edwin: All the *noun* senses are extremely close in meaning anyway. The biggest difference I can see is that a *constant* can be a ***symbol*** denoting a ***value*** that doesn't change, or it can be an actual ***thing*** that doesn't change and/or is always around. Either sense could be easily derived from the other in any given context, I'd have thought.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And presumably the non-mathematical sense came first (in time)?

Comment: @TrevorD: OED: French *constant* (14th cent. in Littré), < Latin *constāns, constānt-em* standing firm, firm, immovable, stable, etc. Even [the gravitational constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment) hadn't been identified when the word got started, let alone our standard "constant" today (**c** = speed of light, as in **E=mc²**).

Answer (score 2):

I read it as meaning that *events on the ground* (as opposed to diplomatic initiatives) have been constantly (or continuously) dictating the way things have developed. On the other hand, diplomats have constantly (or continuously) been trying to *catch-up* with developments on the ground, whereas they would prefer to be taking the lead.

Answer (score 1):

> "*Does s/he mean constant as in a maths equation's constant?*"

I believe so. While reading the passage, the oft-mentioned aphorism 'Change is the new constant' came to mind. The author may have been restating this, albeit in an overly verbose fashion. As for your second question, your guess is only slightly better than mine. I'm not really knowledgeable on the conflicts occuring in the Middle East right now. But I'm pretty sure somebody else will give you some insight. Hope that helps!